# Show that $d_V(x,y)$ is metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Question: On the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, show that the function $d$, defined as follows, is a metric: 
$$d_V(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if}\ x=y  \\ \min{\{\dfrac{1}{n!}}\}\mid\ n!\ \text{divides}\ |x - y| & \text{if}\ x\neq y \end{cases}$$
All I have tried is: (1st)  $d_V(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$; (2nd)  $d_V(x,y)= d_V(y,x)$; (3rd) $d_V(x,y) + d_V(y,z)\geq (?) d_V(x,z)$:

Case 1:  If $d_V(x,z)=0$, apparently for any $d_V(x,y)$ and $d_V(y,z)$, $d_V(x,y) + d_V(y,z)\geq d_V(x,z)$.

Case 2: If $d_V(x,z)= \min{\{\dfrac{1}{n!}}\}|\ n!\ \text{divides}\ |x - z|=\min\dfrac{k}{| x - z|}$, then there are $3$ possibilities for pair of $(d_V(x,y), d_V(y,z))$, $2$ states when one of them is $0$, and the other if non of them are $0$. For example for the last state we have to prove: $\min\dfrac{l}{| x - y|} + \min\dfrac{m}{| y - z|}\geq \min\dfrac{k}{| x - z|}$ such that $l, m, k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't know how to complete it. Would you please guide me how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d_V(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{m!}$ and $d_V(y,z) = \dfrac{1}{n!}$, then  $m!$ divides $|x-y|$ and $n!$ divides $|y-z|$. In particular $m!$ divides $x-y$ and $n!$ divides $y-z$.

Assume without loss of generality that $m \le n$. Then $m!$ divides $n!$, so that $m!$ divides both $x-y$ and $y-z$. Thus $m!$ also divides $x-z$.  It follows that $m!$ divides $|x-z|$ and thus
$$d_V(x,z) \le \frac{1}{m!} < \frac{1}{m!} + \frac{1}{n!} = d_V(x,y) + d_V(y,z)$$ so you have a metric.